# Microsoft Graph API - An error occurred sending the request on reading file

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I m trying to read a file from OneDrive using official SDK and a code from [OneDrive API Browser Sample](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sample-apibrowser-dotnet) as follows.

```
var stream = await graphClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items[item.Id].Content.Request().GetAsync();
```

Where `drive.Id` and `item.Id` are valid IDs retrieved by previous successful calls to Graph.

I receive the following error.

> An error occurred sending the request.
> Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException   at
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.GetResultCore(Boolean
> waitCompletionNotification)

Another time I got more detailed exception.

> at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.d__21.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.d__20.MoveNext()    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at Microsoft.Graph.HttpProvider.d__19.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__36.MoveNext()    at
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()    at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.Graph.BaseRequest.d__34.MoveNext()
> at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
> at
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
> task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I ve spent a lot of time and started to suspect throttling. But it was hard to decide exactly. Then I gave up and put it aside for 3 days. After a pause, I retried very same code and it worked perfectly. I assume it was throttling.

Answer (score 1):

Try this -

```
// get reference to stream of file in OneDrive
GraphServiceClient graphClient = GetAuthenticatedGraphClient(...);
var fileStream = graphClient.Drives[drive.Id].Items[fileId]
                                     .Content
                                     .Request()
                                     .GetAsync()
                                     .Result;

var currentFolder = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();
var driveItemPath = Path.Combine(currentFolder, "proposal.docx");

// save stream to the local file
var driveItemFile = System.IO.File.Create(driveItemPath);
fileStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
fileStream.CopyTo(driveItemFile);
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, @Shweta. Funny enough, I started from this. But had request errors. Then I thought that it is due to sync call and rewrote code async. It failed also. I ve spent a lot of time and started to suspect throttling. But it was hard to decide exactly. Then I gave up and put it aside for 3 days. After a pause, I retried very same code and it worked perfectly. I assume it was throttling. I do not mark your suggestion as answer. Your code is correct. My code is also correct. Throttling seems real reason.